# iTunes Newsstand Cover art changed to default image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, newsstand-kit

I had released some newsstand applications on app store and the cover art was getting displayed on app store and itunes properly till last week. It was getting updated whenever i was updating the same on itunesconnect newsstand section.

Suddenly all the cover art of my applications are changed to default cover art on itunes and app store.

I verified itunesconnect that there is an active issue with an end date in future. Also, image uploaded is a PNG with resolution 72pixels.

I edited the cover art multiple times, but didn't get it changed in app store.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cover art will be changed to default when there is a discrepancy with the cover art of the current issue. Please verify whether your uploaded image has a minimum 1024 pixels on the long edge.